# JavaScript - How to get the proper byte size in blob when chunk upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, file

I have implemented the chunk upload feature in my component. For this used `file.slice` method to split the file like below,

```
` var start = 0, end = chunkSize;
 while (start < fileSize) {
    var blob = file.slice(start, end-1);
    formData.append('chunkFile', blob, file.name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) { console.log(e); }, false);
    xhr.open('POST', '../saveUrl');
    xhr.send(formData);
    start = end;
    end += chunkSize;
}`
```

But the generated chunk files are looks **repeated** the first chunk file. For example, I have uploaded a 5MB image file, split as 1MB chunk files. But the result is all the 5 chunk files are same as first chunk file.

Could you please guide me, how to get the other split chunk files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Prasanth, This issue occurs due to latest blob not updated properly